# Windows get shared/networked printers only

Tags: java, windows, network-programming, printers

Greetings All!
          I am working on a java project where I am suppose to get shared printers in windows, I have a shared/networked printer:

[image]

as you can see in above picture i have highlighted shared Icon. I have tried powershell and wmic (using command line) in both cases i get Shared = False and Network = False. I am mostly java guy so just wondering if there are any suggestions please.
here is response for:

```
wmic printer get name,shared,servername,SystemName,ShareName,PortName,network,local
```

[image]

Kind Regards
FI

Comment: When the printer is a network printer then the shared state should be returned as true by following command `wmic printer get name,shared,servername`.

Comment: as mentioned above it returns shared = False

Comment: That sounds strange. Could you share the output of `wmic printer get name,shared,servername,SystemName,ShareName,PortName,network,local`.

Comment: thanks for your reply @SubOptimal, I have edited the question and placed image there as output for above

Comment: This shows the printer is not connected to a shared network printer, but rather to via [WSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Devices). That's why `Shared/Network` shown as false. Maybe the column `PrintProcessor` could be used to identify such port.